# Create array 2 dimension in Python without knowing size of array

Tags: python, python-2.7

How to create array 2D in python when I don't know size of array 2D:

```
myList =[[1,2,3],
          [1,3],
         [1,2,8],
         .....]
```

my code is :

```
myList=[[]]
for i in range(0,len(data)):
   for k in range(0,len(data)):
      if (true conditional):
           myList[i].append(k)
```

my error:

> IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: what is `data` and `true conditional`?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Your first statement doesn't create a 2D list, it creates a list with one element that is an empty list. Your syntax isn't quite right for the loops, but sticking with it for illustrative purposes, you want something like:

```
myList = []
for i in len(data):
  myList.append([])
  for k in len(data):
    if (true conditional):
      myList[i].append(k)
```

Comment: This code would produce a `TypeError`, which, when fixed, would allow an `IndexError`.

Comment: Right, sorry, I was sleeping at the keyboard. Will fix.

Comment: Thank you, I got the answer. I can fix my code with your code. :)

Answer (score 0):

Your loops look a little funny.  If you want to loop with `i` and `k` being integers, try:

```
myList=[[]]
for i in range(len(data)):
   for k in range(len(data)):
      if (true conditional):
           myList[i].append(k)
```

Right now, `for i in len(data):` is trying to iterate over the return value of `len(data)` which is a number, the length of `data`, not a list.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not very clear about your problem. However, you may try this:

```
myList = []
for i in xrange(len(data)):
    myList.append([k for k in len(data) if true-condition])
```

Comment: In Python, a list is dynamic

Answer (score 0):

I can fix my problem

```
myList=[]
    for i in range(0,len(data)):
        myList.append([])
        for k in range(0,len(data)):
             if (true conditional):
                  myList[i].append(k)
```